# Alter session "on calling" a query via Oracle DB-Link

Tags: oracle, session, dblink, nls-sort, nls-comp

I have a problem with a remote database and a functional index.
When I call a query on a DB link from databases with "normal index", this DB passes the session parameters from the database that calls the DB link.
But I need the session parameters configured in the remote DB (NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC & NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI).

Is it possible to change the session of the calling database when opening the db link?
So that automatically the session is changed, if e.g. a select * from table@remote.db is sent.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to alter session over database link.

I don't know what exactly you're doing (as you didn't post any code), but - if you used appropriate **hint** (`driving_site`) and apply `nls_sort` in query, perhaps it'll do what you wanted.

This is a stupid example, but illustrates what I'm trying to say:

```
SQL> select /*+ driving_site (t) */
  2    t.name, d.loc
  3  from dept d cross join test@dbl_mike t
  4  where t.name = 'Little'
  5    and rownum = 1
  6  order by nlssort(name, 'NLS_SORT = GERMAN');

NAME       LOC
---------- -------------
Little     NEW YORK

SQL>
```

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with the code, since it's a simple "select * from table@remotedb".
My problem is, that the source db overwrite the target db session parameter. I tried to set a logon-trigger on the target db, but this also overwritten.

Next idea was, with opt_param hint, but this also not working:
select /*+ opt_param('NLS_SORT',BINARY_CI) opt_param('NLS_COMP',LINGUISTIC) */ * From TABLE@REMOTEDB;

Comment: Ah, it is not that **I** want to do anything with your code. I just thought that it would be simpler - for the community - if you posted some more info. For example, as line #6 in my code shows, NLS_SORT can be used directly in ORDER BY clause so maybe you don't have to ALTER SESSION in order to set it. Anyway: that's pretty much everything I can say about it. I hoped that it might do some good. Sorry if it doesn't, but I do hope that someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: No problem ;) for my problem, no much code is needed, i think. thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, if you wonder if it was me who downvoted your question - nope, wasn't me.